# How do I handle two elements at a time in an array (for loop) with batch?

Tags: arrays, windows, batch-file

I am trying to create some sort of handler for arguments passed into my script. The idea is to handle "pairs" of arguments together. So, that is to say 1 and 2, 3 and 4, 5 and 6, and so on... (**NOT** 2 and 3, 4 and 5, 6 and 7, and so on...)

I think batch is very cool, but I am very new to batch. I am lost as how to do it. So far I have managed to successfully put the arguments into an array with the following script:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a count+=1
set "params[%count%]=%~1"
shift
if defined params[%count%] (
    goto :repeat
) else (
    set /a count-=1
)
```

Now I just need to handle each of the elements in pairs. I don't know how to do this at all. I know how to handle the elements individually with `for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%s in ('set params[') do`, but I don't know how to do pairs

**on the side** can someone explain what the delayed expansion thing is supposed to do?

**just for clarity,** by "handle" I mean to manipulate it and pass it on as an argument onto another script. this must be done in pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: remove variables starting $ or #
For %%b IN ($ #) DO FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set %%b 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

SET /a count=0
SET "select=this is select's original value"

ECHO parameters received = %*

:loop
REM SET $... and #... to the parameter-pair.
SET $%count%=%1
SET #%count%=%2
IF NOT DEFINED $%count% GOTO process
IF NOT DEFINED #%count% ECHO "Incomplete pair"&GOTO :EOF
SET /a count +=1
:: shift twice to move 2 parameters
shift&shift&GOTO loop

:process
ECHO %count% pairs found
SET $
SET #

FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%count%) DO (
 REM note that this changes "select"
 SET /a select=%%a - 1
 CALL SET /a item1=%%$!select!%%
 CALL SET /a item2=%%#!select!%%

 ECHO pair %%a is !item1! and !item2! from $!select! and #!select! NOT $#%select%
)

ECHO ----------------- select = %select% ----------
SET /a count-=1

FOR /L %%a IN (0,1,%count%) DO (
 REM note that this changes "select"
 SET /a select=%%a + 1

 ECHO pair !select! is !$%%a! and !#%%a! from $%%a and #%%a NOT $#%select%

GOTO :EOF
```

First, set up some initial values. The first `for` ensures that any variables starting `$` or `#` are cleared.

Set `$0` and `#0` to the first and second parameters. If $0 is not set, then we have no further data, so process what we have. If $0 is set but #0 is not, we don't have a pair so complain and terminate.

If both #0 ans $0 are set, increment `count`, `shift` the parameters twice and run around the loop. The next pair will be placed in $/#1 and so on until the parameters are exhausted.

Now show the count of parameters and the `$` and `#` values that have been set.

Next loop show unnecessary manipulation of the variables.

- First set `select` to 1 less than the loop-counter.
- then use a parsing trick to get the value of $[current value of select]. The line translates to  "SET /a item1=%$n%" where `n` is the *run-time* value of `select` - ie. the value as it changes through the loop.
- then show the results. `item1` is changed within the block (parenthesised series of statements) so we need `!item1` to access that changed value - `%item1%` would give us the value as it was when the loop was `parsed`. You can see that from the report for `select` on the same line.

Last loop is the same idea - but varying %%a from 0 to (count-1). Observe that `select` in the dashed `echo` line has the last value it was assigned in the previous loop.

So, once again we change `select` within the block, so we see a difference between `!select!` and `%select%`. We can also access `$0` directly using `!$%%a!` - that is the current value of the variable [`$` strung with the current value of the loop-control `%%a`]

Comment: Thanks for this answer. There was only one issue. From what I understand `set /a` only stores numeric values. What if my arguments are strings? (I am refering to `set /a item1` and `set /a item2`)

Comment: also what does `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` do?

Comment: I am sorry. these^ were my comments. I was logged into my brother's account

Comment: Certainly. Use the syntax `set "varname=%~1"` to assign a string instead. It will work just the same. Batch actually only uses strings. The `~` strips any enclosing `"` from the element, so you coud invoke *yourbatch* 3 "some item" for instance. Note that the quotes in the `set` command I've mentioned ensure that any trailing spaces on the batch line are not included in the value assigned (which can be hard-to-find)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Store arguments one by one
set "count=0"
:repeat
   set /A count+=1
   set "param[%count%]=%~1"
   shift
if "%~1" neq "" goto repeat

rem Show arguments in pairs
set /A countMIN1=count-1
for /L %%i in (1,2,%countMIN1%) do (
   set /A j=%%i+1
   for %%j in (!j!) do echo !param[%%i]! !param[%%j]!
)
```

For further details, see: [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Comment: I am sorry. I am very new to batch. Could you explain to me what you did, so I can understand?

Comment: I am sorry. that^ was my comment. I was logged into my brother's account

Comment: The first part is your same code, where you create the "param" array with all arguments. In the second part `%%i` is varied as `1,3,5,...` up to N-1, and j is %%i+1, so the `echo !param[%%i]! !param[%%j]!` command show params 1 and 2 first, then params 3 and 4, etc...